# Visual Studio 2015: Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, mscorlib

I am trying to update a service reference but I'm getting the following error:

Could not resolve mscorlib for target framework '.NETFramework,Version=v4.0'. 
   This can happen if the target framework is not installed or if the framework 
   moniker is incorrectly formatted.

- .NET v4.0 is installed.
- Both "Update service Reference" and "Configure Service Reference"
  give the same error.

Answer (score 3):

i opened the project file in a notepad editor and removed this.

> Target Name="EnsureNuGetPackageBuildImports"  /> bla bla bla

Comment: Worked like charm!

Comment: Worked perfectly even in VS 2022

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have a bad service reference configuration

try the following

1. open csproj file in any text editor
2. then remove all references to any soap service or its files
3. save and open the project in visual studio

Answer (score 0):

In my project, the nuget packages were not being restored correctly due to some connectivity issues. Once the nuget packages have been restored successfully, the error went away.